# Remove the vertical line black between two TIFF files to create a mosaic

Tags: raster, geotiff-tiff, line, delete, black

How can I remove the vertical line between two TIFF files to create a tile?

For example:

[image]

The black line showing the red arrow

I have tried:

```
gdal_calc.py -A DEM.vrt --outfile=DEM_clean.tif --calc="A*(A>=-3.4028234663852886e+38)" --NoDataValue=0 --type=Float32
```

Comment: Is there a gap between the tiles? Load both in QGIS (or your favorite GIS viewer) and zoom in to see if the tiles align properly. While you're there interogate the merged raster  to see what the value is of the vertical line. It is possible to interpolate but that should be a last resort.